# "Медвежатники"

Tags: этимология

Почему воров-взломщиков называют "медвежатниками"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Большие стационарные сейфы издавна называют "медведями". По признаку размера и неуклюжести.
Отсюда и медвежатники.